# Creating a combobox in a jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using the following to create a datatable.

```
   mydata = [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "daniel",
        "age": "28",
        "position": "accountant",
        "status": "A"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "jack",
        "age": "55",
        "position": "architect",
        "status": "R"
    }];

   $('#myTable').dataTable({
        "aaData": mydata,
            "aoColumns": [{
            "mDataProp": "id"
        ,{
            "mDataProp": "name"
        }, {
            "mDataProp": "age"
        }, {
            "mDataProp": "position"
        },
          {
            "mDataProp": "status"
        }]
    });
```

Now I need to create a combobox for the column "status" (Options: D, L, A, R) having each status with a separate ID (using ID from the "id" column). As a start I used the mRender function to create a combobox like:

```
 {
            "mDataProp": "status",
             mRender: function(oObj){
                    return '<select id = "status">'+'<option value = "D"> D </option>'+'<option value = "L"> L </option>'+'<option value = "A"> A </option>'+'<option value = "R"> R </option>'+'</select>';
        }
      }
```

This just creates a simple combobox but I want to know as to how would I assign each option with the "id" column. Any suggestions?

Comment: isn't your datatables link *only* for the css? where do you get the datatables.js ?  also: put your code inside `$(document).ready()` ...and you're probably getting an error in your console, what's the error?

Comment: I included the datatables.js cdn and it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: What I also would like to know is that if I have "myData" as a seperate json file, how would I go around pointing to it? I believe $.getJSON() and $.ajax would require a url.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your JSON file from a different absolute URL (e.g., `www.example.com/files/myJson.JSON`) or from a relative URL (e.g., `/files/myJson.JSON`)

The rest is pretty simple.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON( "<<LOCATION OF YOUR FILE>>", function( data ) {
var mydata = data;

$('#myTable').dataTable({
    "aaData": mydata,
        "columns": [{
        "data": "name"
    }, {
        "data": "age"
    }, {
        "data": "position"
    }]
   });
  });
});
```

Keep your HTML as is. Note that I simplified your Datatables formatting, as you were using labels from an older version.

Comment: Thanks jonmrich. I tried this but I got an error on my console that says GET file:///C:/Users/data.json net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. I checked for typos and my relative path and everything seems to be the way it should be.

Comment: This is suggesting that this is pointing to a local machine, is that where all of  this is running?

Comment: Yes. All of this is running on my local machine.

Comment: Put the file in the same folder as your javascript and HTML and make this line like so: `$.getJSON( "XXX", function( data ) {` Replace XXX with the NAME of your file, slashes or file path.

Comment: I had all my files in the same folder. For some reason $.getJSON() only accepts url's like REST uri's. I also read posts about people facing similar problems. I got this working by just including the JSON input in my script. Thanks for your help! :)